# Bitmap density on openGL ES textures (Android)

Tags: android, bitmap, textures

I'm having trouble with loading textures regarding their resolution on openGL for Android. If the texture is 256x256 everything works perfectly, but if it's other resolution, the program throws this exception on start:

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x........

I found a code on the internet that changes the density of the bitmap this way:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inDensity = 240;
```

and by doing this, I can load 512x512 textures. But I'm not able to load for example 128x128 bitmaps, because I don't know which density I have to use. I'm not sure either that this is the normal procedure to load textures, because I don't found many information on the internet.

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has this problem, or the textures show up messed up (like ones being another, or other weird things) I was able to solve it by deleting all the items on the "drawable" folder and putting them in again. It seems the pointers to the images were corrupted or something.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to specify the density, you just have to make sure the image is a power of 2, which you seem to have done. I would leave out the density option and just specify Config.ARGB_8888;

If this doesnt fix the problem can you show your code for loading the texture

Comment: That doesn't change the problem, but I was able to solve it by deleting all the items on the "drawable" folder and putting them in again. It seems the pointers to the images were corrupted or something. Thank you anyway!